# Prove that the conjugate transpose is bijective too

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism, transpose

Let $T:\mathcal{V}\to\mathcal{W}$ be a linear map and let it be bijective. How can I prove now that its conjugate transpose, $A^*$ is bijective too?

My idea was that if $T$ is bijective then there exists a $T^{-1}$, so we know that $\det{A}\ne 0$, where $T(v)=Av$. Now we know that $\det{A^*}=\overline{\det{A}}\ne 0$, so we know $T^*$ has also an inverse $T^{*-1}$ and that means it should also be bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that $(U\circ T)^*=\operatorname{Id}^*=\operatorname{Id}$, but also $\,(U\circ T)^*= T^*\circ U^*$.

This proves $T^*$ and $U^*$ are inverse to each other.

Comment: I have proven that $(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*$, is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. It proves at the same time $T*$ is invertible, and its inverse is the transconjugate of the inverse of $T$.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry I'm a few years late, but I'm getting ready for my final and I'm trying to prove your second statement. Could you tell me how can I do it?